# Function returning 2 different results - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used this site before for help with various things in the past, and in this instance, I couldn't find anything in the search box, so apologies if this exists elsewhere.

In sql server 2005, I have several stored procedures that change various bits of code, and recently we have created a function that adds spaces into a defined string. So in theory, I pass a string into it, and I get a result as blocks of 4. When I run this manually, and define the actual text, it splits fine (I get #### 0000 012 returned) but when I execute the function within the SP, I get #### 0012 0012. Is there any reason why?

I have set a print command to the string before it gets passed into my function, and it prints "####0000012   " and the print after is "#### 0012 0012"

Below is the function code, with no declares:

```
 set ANSI_NULLS ON
 set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO


 ALTER function [dbo].[udf_addspaces](@string varchar(255),@lengthbetween int)
 returns varchar(100)
 as
 BEGIN
    declare @i int, @stringlen float, @output varchar(255), @outputofloop varchar(4)

    set @stringlen = LEN(@string)/@lengthbetween
    set @output =''
    set @i = 0
    while @i <= @stringlen
    BEGIN
        set @outputofloop = left(@string,@lengthbetween)

        if @lengthbetween < LEN(@string)
        BEGIN
            set @string = right(@string,LEN(@string)-@lengthbetween)
        END

        set @output = @output + @outputofloop +' '

        set @i = @i+1
    END
    return @output
 END
```

Here is the bit of the SP that executes this:

```
 set @Consignment2 = (@Consignment) + rtrim(@Check14)
 print @Consignment2
 set @Consignment2 = dbo.udf_addspaces(@Consignment2,4)
 print @Consignment2
```

Here are the lines it prints: (Note: #### replaces a 4 digit number, removed for security reasons)

```
 ####0000012   
 #### 0012 0012
```

Regards,
Luke M

Comment: Please include the Function header as well.  Even better would be to include sufficient code and data that would allow us to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: You are missing a lot of information - function header, the input for the given example, and the SP code.

Comment: Ive added more bits and the rest of the function, im a bit new to this so wasn't sure how much is needed. I cant put the whole SP here, for security reasons

Comment: Could you add a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6f79/1)? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Im not too sure what a SQL fiddle is. Ive looked at the one posted, and its a little different with the declare. I changed this to match mine, and I replicated the error.
When set to declare it as a char(14) it breaks, yet as a varchar(255) it worked fine? I have applied this change to the live environment for me, and it has fixed it. Can I ask why having it as a char(14) would break it in that way? (If not for my benefit - for anyone else that reads this with possibly the same issue)

Comment: Funny, the output that *I* get from this is `"#### 0000 0012 0012 "`.

Comment: I checked again, and when I make the change to char(14) I definitely get #### 0012 0012. (matches the exact issue I had). I now have it fixed, and I can now make sure the change matches, so Im happy enough that my issue is fixed, I just don't know why the error is there on a char(14). I normally use varchars, but have been trying to neaten my code up (as its for someone else)

Answer (score 0):

1. Even though you've defined `stringlen` as a float, it will be an integer value, because the two values you're dividing are ints.
2. There's a difference between a `char(14)` mentioned in your comments, to a `varchar(14)`.  The char(14) is guaranteed to be 14 characters long. The varchar may not be.

I think the body of your function could be more succinctly expressed as this...

```
declare @result varchar(500)
    select @result = '' 
    select 
        @result = @result 
            + substring(@string, number*@lengthBetween+1, @lengthBetween) 
            + ' '
    from master..spt_values 
    where type='p' 
    and number <= (len(@string)/@lengthBetween)

    return rtrim(@result)
```